# Remove everything except this text by regex

Tags: regex

I have a long list of these lines:

```
https://123.com/@jcandelas/comicsnow!-jvttr855z/-/a-re0Um1B6T9anGRJvCUOLcA:a:37070831-/0
https://123.com/@mccluret/raise-the-apple-b1b1lv45z/-/a-p6LFvKnsSzmeM0wqRbq-nw:a:3679520-/0
```

I want to remove everything except 
https:// 123.com/@*/
where * can be anything

(ignore the extra space after https:// as stackoverflow does not allow me to post more than 2 links

so the end result for the 2 above links should be

```
https:// 123.com/@mccluret/

https:// 123.com/@jcandelas/
```

Please give me the find and replace query I need to enter to do this.

Comment: *give me the find and replace query* in what language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use capturing group.

```
\b(https:\/\/123\.com\/@[^\/]*\/).*
```

REplace with `$1`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nI6uL1/5)

Comment: No idea why people downvoted this. I searched and there is no answer to this issue to be found elsewhere. Am i right to assume this place is full of self righteous and pompous trolls?